# How to make Tilda works with zsh?

Tags: zsh, tilda

I followed the steps listed here: 
http://whaaat.com/content/update-shell-zsh-osx-unix
And if I hit `ctrl + shift + T`, `zsh` opens up, but if I start Tilda, it still uses `bash`.

BUT, the tricky part: if I `sudo su` on Tilda, `zsh` appears!

What is happening?

Comment: If I open my terminal it goes to zsh. The problem is with Tilda.

Comment: Which terminal is that? What does `getent passwd $USER | awk -F: '{print $NF}'` say?

Comment: I seem that you accidentally changed the login shell of root instead of your user. Did you perchance run all steps as root or with `sudo`? The guide you linked does not seem to mention which steps need to be done with root permissions (only the installation of zsh with `apt-get`) and which should be done as normal user (all other).

Comment: `echo $0` returns me `/bin/bash`, while  `getent passwd $USER | awk -F: '{print $NF}'` returns me `/bin/zsh`